# Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME issue when using Flask @app.before_request

Tags: python, html, css, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to add a maintenance page to my Flask site. I have created a route called /maintenance that renders my maintenance.html template. I then added an @app.before_request to check whether the site is in maintenance mode (a Boolean value).

When I request the /maintenance route directly from the browser, the page displays fine:

[image: maintenance page called directly from browser]

However, when the route is called from the @app.before_request, it displays like this:

[image: maintenance page called from @app.before_request]

As can be seen from the console window, I'm getting the following message:
'Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html'

Here is the code for the /maintenance route and @app.before_request:

```
@app.before_request
def check_for_maintenance():
    if maintenance == True and request.path != url_for('maintenance'):
        return redirect(url_for('maintenance'))

@app.route('/maintenance')
def maintenance():
    if request.method =='GET':
        return render_template('maintenance.html')
```

Here's the code for the maintenance page (ish, it inherits lots of parent Jinja templates but the important stuff is here):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/theme.css">
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='fonts/peenu/stylesheet.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}" rel="icon">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="maintenanceBackground">
      <div id="maintenanceTextParent">
        <img id="spannerIcon" src="/static/media/graphics/spanner.png" alt="Spanner icon">
        <h1 id="maintenanceText1">We're doing some work at the moment</h1>
        <h2 id="maintenanceText2">We hope to be running again soon. Please try again later.</h2>
        <img id="whiteLogo" src="/static/media/graphics/logoWhite.png" alt="Custom Crochet logo">
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat related to flask. If you try to access the html directly without flask's webserver, the html page loads with applied css, as expected.

To be more specific, actual solution is

- to create a "css" folder in "static" folder.
- add css in path of ".css" file (update all occurrence for any .css file with expected relative path)
  eg.
- change => href="{{ url_for('static', filename='stylesheet.css') }}" to href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/stylesheet.css') }}" OR
- change => href="../static/main.css" to href="../static/css/main.css"

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

In your case

- try moving stylesheet.css from "fonts/peenu/stylesheet.css" to "static/css" folder.
- change => href="{{ url_for('static', filename='fonts/peenu/stylesheet.css') }}"
  to
  href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/stylesheet.css') }}"

I had spent some time on this issue and was able to resolve it with above mentioned solution.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29893271)